# jquery span tag

Tags: jquery, html

In my code I have this:

```
<textarea id="screen" cols="40" rows="20" readonly> </textarea>
```

which displays the data in the `screen` id, obviously.

But when I change it to:

```
<span id="screen"></span>
```

or

```
<div id="screen"></div>
```

it shows nothing.

Go easy on me i'm a rookie.

### additional info

this is in my script tag in the head section:

```
function update()
{
$.post("chat_new_serv.php", {}, function(data){ $("#screen").val(data);});  

setTimeout('update()', 3000);
}

$(document).ready(

function() 
{
 update();

 $("#button").click(    
  function() 
  {         
   $.post("chat_new_serv.php", 
{ message: $("#message").val()},
function(data){ 
$("#screen").val(data); 
$("#message").val("");
}
);
  }
 );
});
```

The new_chat_serv page just outputs the chat text from the database.

Comment: Where/how are you setting the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val()` will only get/set the contents of input elements (`TEXTAREA` included). Use `html()` or `text()` to get/set the contents of other HTML tags.

From your code:

```
$("#screen").val(data);
```

Would become:

```
$("#screen").html(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

For `<textarea>` you can use `.val()`, but for `<div>` and `<span>` you want to use `.html()` or `.text()`.